# Is it possible to convert movement animation of the floating object into animation keys?

Tags: animation, export, ocean-simulation

I created an Ocean simulation, with an object "floating" on it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZUkHyDC1lk&feature=youtu.be

Now I need to export this to Nuke, so I need to convert the movement of the floating object to animation keys - floating object repeats location and rotation of the ocean, in the area that I'm drawing using invisible object (dinamic paint).

Can I somehow convert movement animation of the floating object into animation keys?

Comment: 90% of what you wrote is irrelevant.

Comment: @someonewithpc Yes, but I added a description of "my plan", and highlight it in the text as a separate part. I did it because my main goal - to get an object that moves and turns in the same way as a floating object (no matter what the object is), and perhaps there are other ways to solve this problem except the way in which I asked about. So I left this additional information in case someone offers another way.

Comment: Then that's a different question and should be asked separately

Comment: @someonewithpc Sorry if I confused you. In my scene object floating in the water, so it moves a little bit and turns. If I animate it manually, I would have used a key animation - from key to key, from phase to phase. But there is another way animation works - floating object receives information about how to move by analyzing the surface of the ocean, (here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11F1NRpqrzY). But I can't export this animation to Maya or Nuke - because it depends on the "ocean modifier" which does not exist in Maya and Nuke.

Comment: 1) How to do it? If I click apply, the ocean freezes. 2) Anyway animation of the floating object will be calculated using the "copy location" and "Copy rotation" (constraints menu), I think in Maya and Nuke these tools don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! :) You can use the "Bake action"!

If you have an ocean, and an object that "floats" on the surface of the ocean using the method, described in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11F1NRpqrzY)

[image]

do the following:

1) Select a floating object

2) Press T and in the left pane, select the tab "Animation"

3) Press Bake Action, select the frame range and check "clear constraints"

[image]
[image]

4) Voila! You will see a lot of yellow strips in the timeline - the key frames of animation.

[image]

Now, if you delete the ocean and sphere by which you drew in the dynamic Paint mode, floating object will continue to move as before.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some more detail, i.e. what needs to be selected, and an example of the result?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Sure, done! :)